# SQL query to join "GeneralJournalAccountEntry" to table "CustInvoiceTrans" to get column value "MainAccount"

Tags: sql-server, data-warehouse, dynamics-ax-2012

We have a Dynamics AX 2012 environment backed by SQL Server.  We load invoice line data from table "CustInvoiceTrans" into an EDW fact table.  We are wanting to find what the "MainAccount" column value is for each invoice line as it relates to table "GeneralJournalAccountEntry".  This would need to be done through a SQL query.

I have attempted an Internet search on the topic, but found nothing definitive.  I have also searched through the AX SQL views hoping to find a solution there, but did not come across anything.  It is possible that I could be missing something though.

SQL Pseudo Example:

```
SELECT CIT.InvoiceID
        ,CIT.InvoiceDate
        ,CIT.SalesPrice
        ,GJAE.MainAccount
FROM CustInvoiceTrans CIT
LEFT JOIN {..Some table(s)} ST
    ON ST.{SomeColumn} = CIT.{SomeColumn}
LEFT JOIN GeneralJournalAccountEntry GJAE
    ON GJAE.{SomeColumn} = ST.{SomeColumn}
```

If this is possible, it would assume that one invoice line relates to one general ledger account entry line to return one MainAccount.  I am uncertain if an invoice line could be split among multiple general ledger account entry lines.

Comment: Hi you will need to find column(s) between the 2 tables that will help you with the join. Without knowing much about the table structure (which would help) . But a sample data from 2 tables would be great. And your expected output based on that sample data.

Comment: invoice table may or may not have multiple entries (you are going to take it the business route). Keep it technical and I'm sure someone will be able to help you get the desired resultset.

Comment: @junketsu, yes, you are correct.  That is the crux of my problem.  If I could find an ERD that showed how these tables are related, then I would be in business.  Unfortunately, my research has not come with this this information.  I'm hoping that someone with a better familiarity of AX 2012 processes and DB schema will point me in the right direction.  I also realize this joining these two tables might not even be possible.

Comment: yeah you could possible be missing few interim tables. No one will probly be able to help you if you cannot provide the 3 things requested. :(

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you are worried that you might end up with duplicates when you join the GeneralJournalAccountEntry table? My example shows how you can ensure that the GeneralJournalAccountEntry table has a 1:1 relationship with the CustInvoiceTrans table. I've assumed:

- That there is a primary key for your accounts and customers (AccountId and CustomerId)
- That there is some table that maps customer's to accounts

  SELECT
      cit.InvoiceID
      , cit.InvoiceDate
      , cit.SalesPrice
      , t.MainAccount
  FROM (
      SELECT
          gjae.AccountId
          , gjae.MainAccount
      FROM GeneralJournalAccountEntry gjae
      GROUP BY
          gjae.AccountId
          , gjae.MainAccount
  ) t
  JOIN [SomeTable] st
      ON st.AccountId = t.AccountId
  JOIN CustInvoiceTrans cit
      ON cit.CustomerId = st.CustomerId

Comment: Any tips on formatting? I don't know why all of my line breaks don't show up and why indenting the query didn't format it as code. I used the toolbar to try and format it as code...

Comment: My first priority is to figure out what tables in the AX database can possibly be used to make this join between customer invoice lines and GL account entries.  Then after that, I would be concerned about checking for duplicates if the join is even possible.  As for formatting, I did just what you described, formatted my SQL as "Code", which preserved the line breaks, converted to mono-space font and grey background.  When you do this, you should be able to see it in the formatted preview of the post.  Unsure why it didn't work for your post.

Comment: See here for what tables to use: [link](https://dynamicsuser.net/ax/f/developers/90253/relation-between-custinvoicetrans-and-generaljournalaccountentry)

Comment: I did run across this link in my research and thought it might be promising.  The issue is that I have a test transaction with two invoice lines.  One invoice line does have a ledgerdimension value that matches a line in then GL, but unfortunately, then second has a value of 0, so I can't match that to any of the other GL lines for the transaction.